# FullCalendar 4.1 and calling refreshevents

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

FullCalendar 4.1.0, Windows 10, VisualStudio 2019

I have the following, lightly edited, code that works:

```
var calendar = undefined;

$(function() {
    calendarInit();
});

function calendarInit() {
    try {
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(
            document.getElementById("calendar"), {
                'plugins': [
                    "interaction",
                    "dayGrid",
                    "timeGrid",
                    "bootstrap",
                    "list",
                    "moment",
                    "momentTimezone"
                ],
                'themeSystem': "bootstrap4",
                'titleFormat': "MMM D, YYYY",
                ...
                'events': function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                    $.get({
                        'url': `/Thing/GetEvents`,
                        'data': {
                            'device': machine,
                            'start': myStart,
                            'end': myEnd
                        },
                        'dataType': "json",
                        'traditional': true
                    }).done(function(ajaxData, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                        successCallback(ajaxData.events);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        ...
                    });
                }
            });

        calendar.render();

        $("body").on("fullCalendar.refetchEvents", function(e) {
            calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
        });

    } catch (e) {
        throw `calendarInit: ${e.message}`;
    }
}
```

The calendar appears, events are shown.  I have a homegrown module that handles a popup form for entering new event data when a range is selected in a `dayView`.  If the module succeeds then it "triggers" a custom `jquery` event `fullCalendar.refetchEvents`.

The last little bit in the `try` block catches the custom event but barfs on the `calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");` line.  I am told that `calendar` is not a function.

I have tried what is above as well as:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
```

with the same results.  The `calendar.render();` works just above it and `calendar` should be global.

What am I missing?

Comment: `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");` is the old syntax for fullCalendar version 3 (when it was a jQuery plugin), so you can forget about that

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) the correct syntax is `calendar.refetchEvents()`. So neither of the things you've tried are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I kept only seeing the old docs.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) the correct syntax to call the method is

```
calendar.refetchEvents()
```